# how to copy two table of database data content into on one table only

Tags: php, mysql, database

guy's i want to ask a question about copying a data from two table into one table only

when i have 3 table of database ex. table a, b, c

i want to copy a and b into table c
is it possible to do that?

i have try to use syntax for copy one database into the other database like this but it seems error in the process.

`Insert Into c (1, 2, 3, 4) 
select 1,2,3 from a
select 4,5,6 from b`

i try use simple syntax for copying a data from database like above.

someone please help me with this

Comment: do the 3 tables have identical columns?

Comment: It is possible if a and b have two identical colums, but do they have this?

Comment: You can do this by plsql.but remember columns in third table should me sum of other two tables column.

Comment: Please post the table structure for the three tables you mentioned.  Also tell us how the `a` and `b` tables related to the `c` table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL INSERT INTO SELECT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227556/mysql-insert-into-select-join)

Comment: table a and b has indentical column 

`table a contain name, gender, address`
`table b contain email, phone number`
`table c contain name, gender, address, email, phone number`

Comment: from every table i have `no` as the unique id's

Answer (score 1):

The generic solution for this would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_3 (col1, col2, ..., coln)
SELECT t1c1 as 'col1', t1c2 as 'col2', ..., t1cn as 'coln'
FROM table_1
UNION
SELECT t2c1 as 'col1', t2c2 as 'col2', ..., t2cn as 'coln'
FROM table_2
```

Make sure that the Data Types of corresponding columns match

Comment: from your syntax 
i have try not using `as`, but directly use the table name. but it seems eror

Comment: Did not get your question. Can you please elaborate. What error are you getting?